# Allow inline javascript google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to execute this js code from an extension that modifies your new tab page.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("qnote-text").innerHTML = "⭕ ";
    }
</script>
```

But I always get the same error on chrome console:

`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

It has to be inline.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do - provide a hash of the extension source. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-inline-script

Answer (score 0):

your error message said google-chrome extension does not allow inline script. so, you have to do external script like `<script src="script.js"></script>`